# error: package com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit does not exist

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I usually find answers to all my questions in the net and more often than not in stackoverflow but on this one I've failed so far and it's triggering my first question in this forum... so bear with me:

I'm trying to use [google's email audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) for the first time. The imports referred in the code snippets are

```
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic.GenericEntry;
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailMonitor;
```

I cannot find the library (jar) to add to my code so it fails to compile as it cannot find these classes.

I found this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/audit/v1) to download audit java library but when I press on the actual download it goes to a page saying "No library available".

I also found a gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar but it doesn't include the above classes either.

There are a couple of other questions* in stackoverflow somewhat related to my issue but the answers there didn't help me with how to resolve it.

I'd appreciate some direction on what am I missing.

thanks!!

*sorry I cannot add the links to the questions because my stacoverflow reputation is low - newbie - so can only post 2 links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven Repository to search: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gdata/core/1.47.1

Comment: thanks for this! got the jar containing the classes I need from your link... and your answer was superfast so I can complain! Now... do you know why the jar is -apparently - not in a google page (i.e. more official source)... is the jar from mvnrepository reliable? or should I post these questions elsewhere? thanks again

Comment: Yes, the mvnrepository can be reliable.